# Android Arrange widgets in LinearLayout in perfect ratio using layout_weight

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

In my application I have to arrange my widgets in proper ratio (width). I have 6 widgets and I want to align in the ratio of `2:2:4:4:1:1` considering width only. I tried this one but i am not get the right solution.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/register_header12"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:weightSum="14"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/register_title_image"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_icon_desc"
                android:src="@drawable/logo_blue" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/register_title_name"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bbb"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/bar_button"
                android:text="BBB"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/aaa"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/bar_button"
                android:text="AAA"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/setting"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
                android:onClick="showSettings"

              />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/signout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_blocked_user"
                android:onClick="doSignOut"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Please provide me the best way..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change all of your `android:layout_width`s to 0.  That will allow the weight property to determine the width and should solve your problem.

Comment: this is correct.  It's worth pointing that weight is used to determine how to utilize any *remaining* space, not *total* space.  By setting all widths to 0, all of the space will be considered remaining space.

Comment: You have to quote the value, `android:layout_width="0dp"`.

Comment: Question is about using `layout_weight`

Answer (score 2):

first of all put weightSum=(sum of all layout weight in your case is 14) in your Linear layout,

then make child view width wrap_content and weight attribute as per your ratio.

hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

layout_weight doesn't decide widget size. In layout, each widget measure its size and require space from parent layout. Then parent assign rest of space to all children according to ratio of layout_weight. So, in your case, you may specify layout_width=0. This way, widgets doesn't require any space, then parent layout could assign space according to layout_weight.

Answer (score 0):

Ralgha's answer is correct one. and for code you can refer below code.

Please check code:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/register_header12"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:weightSum="14"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/register_title_image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_icon_desc"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_blue" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/register_title_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bbb"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bar_button"
            android:text="BBB"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/aaa"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bar_button"
            android:text="AAA"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/setting"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:onClick="showSettings"

          />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/signout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_blocked_user"
            android:onClick="doSignOut"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Hope this will help you.